# Docker Redis container - Command option

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a Redis container in Docker and run a command to initialize the data structures. But I can't even get a simple command like `redis-cli SET counter "4"` to work.

But even with a command like `redis-cli --help`, it doesn't work. It seems that after any command, it exists with the line:

```
sockets_server_redis_1 exited with code 1
```

When I use either of the following lines:

```
command: "redis-cli SET counter \"4\" && redis-cli GET counter"
command: sh -c "redis-cli SET counter \"4\" && redis-cli GET counter"
```

the complete output I get is:

```
Attaching to sockets_server_redis_1
redis_1 | Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
sockets_server_redis_1 exited with code 1
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    command: "redis-cli SET counter \"4\" && redis-cli GET counter"
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

However, if I run this command in the CLI through Docker, it works.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why do the set and get commands not work but `redis-cli --help` works?
2. Why does the process exit after the initial command, and how can I initialize the data structures and not have it exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `command` instruction in a Docker Compose file maps to the [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) directive in a Dockerfile, which is the **one and only** command that the container will execute upon launching (the command can always be overridden when you launch the container, which is what docker-compose is doing under the hood when you set that option).

For a Redis container, whose purpose is to bring up a Redis server, the command should always be the command that actually launches the server. When you override it to instead run redis-cli commands, the server does not come up, so the client can't connect and you see the errors you're getting. The `--help` option for redis-cli doesn't open a connection, which is why it doesn't error (to answer your question #1).

For question #2, see above as to why the process is exiting after the `command` runs. To actually solve your problem, there are a range of options, but I would suggest a second container which just runs a script that a) waits until Redis is reachable and b) initializes the data structures once it is. A utility like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) can make step A easier, though you might be able to get away with just Compose's default `depends_on` functionality (it doesn't wait for the actual service to be ready, just the container, but Redis comes up very quickly):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  redis_init:
    image: redis # we need an image with redis-cli available, so might as well re-use it
    command: "redis-cli -h redis SET counter \"4\""
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

From testing locally, this works, though I can't say how reliable it might be on every system.